# Find string data from MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection and have values like this there :

```
"newsletter": "{\"newsletter_user_list_id\":\"11223344\",\"newsletter_id\":\"11111\",\"newsletter_send_id\":\"24111113909\"}",

"useragent": "Mozilla\/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9) AppleWebKit\/537.71 (KHTML, like Gecko)",
```

How to write a query to fetch all the records having the newsletter_user_list_id  '11223344' ?

Comment: Why are you storing the newsletter value as a string? You can parse it as JSON and store it as a JSON object itself.

Comment: For a nested data structure, you can use a dot to represent its level:db.collection.find({newsletter.newsletter_user_list_id:"112233445"})

Answer (score 0):

You have chosen really weird way of storing your data. It looks like you have an object into your newsletter field, but in fact it is a string. So you have 2 options:

- use [$regex](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) to find `newsletter_user_list_id:11223344` and to suffer for the rest of your life with this application.
- convert it to a proper object with proper types (numbers should be numbers, not strings) and to use [object notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) to reach into subdocuments. `db.a.find({'newsletter.newsletter_user_list_id' : 11223344})`

**P.S.** also I can write regex for you, I think I should not do this, because I am afraid that you will stick with this schema.

Comment: The thing is I am dumping the data from another source. So just inserting it as it is.

Comment: so it will be helpful if you can give the regex also.

Comment: @AlwinAugustin do you really understand that this is not how database should work? You should parse your data properly and not to store everything as a giant blob of text.